# Stopping Local Communication in android hotspot

Tags: networking, wifi-hotspot

How can I stop two devices from communicating among themselves if they are connected to my Hot Spot.(for eg I want them to not be able to ping eachother)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to enable [Wireless Isolation mode](http://www.wirelessisolation.com/).

On the Linksys this is called [AP Isolation](http://www.ehow.com/info_12189303_ap-isolation-linksys.html).

From [WirelessIsolation.com](http://www.wirelessisolation.com/):

> Wireless Isolation, sometimes called client isolation, is a setting on
>   a wireless router. When this setting is enabled it prevents a computer
>   that is connected to the network by a wireless connection from
>   accessing computers and resources that are connected to the network by
>   a wired connection. It will also prevent one wirelessly connected
>   device from connecting to another wirelessly connected device. In
>   essence Isolating that device on the wireless network.
>
> This is used as a method of security so that you can provide both
>   wired and wireless connection through the same network without opening
>   up secured computers and resources to potentially unwanted visitors.
>   This can be very helpful in businesses that have a wireless hotspot
>   located in their lobby for example.
>
> Without Wireless Isolation anyone on a wireless internet connection in
>   a wifi hotspot would not only have full access to the computers and
>   resources in the company’s network, but also to the various wireless
>   devices that were using the wifi hotspot at that time.
>
> Most wireless router makers will support wireless isolation in one
>   form or another, if you already have a router and are curious to see
>   if it comes with wireless isolation or not you can check your products
>   manual, or log into your router and check the security tab.

Comment: Thnks for response.... Is wireless Isolation there in Android...... ???

Comment: What are you using for your hot spot?

Comment: Android Tab Nexus 7 with Android 4.2

Comment: I'm a newbie @Android

What I'm Doing Is creating a router/firewall on android... Rest of the policies are ok and managable coz they require iptable tweaking.... But as for LAN traffic I'm unable to controll any thing.... If there are methods to do so Please guide.... and if I need to modify Android OS please point How and where this LAN traffic is managed in androird source... THNAK YOU